# Why aren't all items displayed in the ScrollView?

Tags: react-native, scrollview, expo, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist

I have a Flatlist inside a ScrollView with 100 items, but no matter what height I give to the ScrollView or Flatlist, there are always just 18 items displayed on my Phone. After that the slider of the ScrollView is still scrolling down, but the list ends after 18 items. I want to be able to scroll through the complete list of items with the ScrollView containing the FlatList. I am using a Samsung Galaxy S8+ as a test device.
Here is a snack of the problem: https://snack.expo.io/@christophhummler/stickyheaderscrollscreens

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the **scrollEnabled={false}**, set it to **true** or remove the prop altogether otherwise it may be your todos array

**Edit**

Since you want to create a sticky header you must set the height to be the device **height of screen + height of header**, change styles.scrollView to :

```
scrollView: {
 height: height + 200,
}
```

also on android there is an issue of nesting scrollviews, to enable a nested scrollview add the nestedScrollEnabled prop:

```
<FlatList
  ...
  nestedScrollEnabled={true}
/>
```

You will have to implement logic to enable the Flatlist scroll view when the specific threshholds are met. It works at the moment in conjunction with **scrollEnabled={true}**

i hope this helps

Comment: It is working on iOS, I will check on android, I think the issue is the Nesting inside a scrollview which affects on android, setting the nestedScrollEnabled={true} on scrollview should fix it, will have to confirm first before I can update you